# Animation controller is not working, why?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to create a simple animation for my container but I get this below error. Not sure what is missing in the code.

**Here is the code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HiveForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const HiveForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HiveFormState createState() => _HiveFormState();
}

class _HiveFormState extends State<HiveForm>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;
  late Animation fieldanimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 4));
    fieldanimation = Tween(begin: 0, end: 200).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController,
        curve: Interval(0.10, 0.90, curve: Curves.easeOut)));

    animationController.forward();

    animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Upload Data Here'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 30, right: 30),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            width: (fieldanimation.value).toDouble(),
            height: 50,
            child: Text(
              'About',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is the error I get**

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
> The following assertion was thrown building HiveForm(dirty, dependencies: [_EffectiveTickerMode], state: _HiveFormState#30cf1(ticker active)):
> Cannot lerp between "0" and "200".
>
> The type int returned a double after multiplication with a double value. See "Types with special considerations" at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Tween-class.html for more information.

Comment: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 200.0) or Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 200)

Comment: Tween<double> worked. It was such a silly mistake from my end. Thank you so much